# SVM predictive outcome

Tags: r, svm

I need help in using `svm` in order to predict an outcome:

data looks like group and numeric data

group

e.g.

```
11N
12H
13B
```

numeric data in each group:

```
11.3
14.2
15.6
```

I'm looking for group then predictive outcome

How do I do this in SVM, I have tried

```
sample_n(data, 3)

set.seed(123)

training.samples <- data$group %>%

createDataPartition(p = 0.75, list = FALSE)

train.data  <- data[training.samples, ]

test.data <- data[-training.samples, ]

model <- train(Pen ~., data = train.data, method = "svmRadial",

trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),

preProcess = c("center","scale"),

tuneLength = 10)

model$bestTune

test_pred <- predict(model, newdata= test.data)

confusionMatrix(table(test_pred, test.data))
```

but still receiving:

```
Error in table(test_pred, test.data) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
caret::confusionMatrix(table(test_pred, test.data$Pen))
```

As you have not provided any data, it is very hard to reproduce your error. I am giving an example with `iris` dataset which is not giving me any error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

data <- iris
head(data, 2)

set.seed(123)
training.samples <- data$Species %>%
  createDataPartition(p = 0.75, list = FALSE)

train.data  <- data[training.samples, ]
test.data <- data[-training.samples, ]

model <- train(Species ~., data = train.data, method = "svmRadial",
               trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
               preProcess = c("center","scale"),
               tuneLength = 10)

model$bestTune
#      sigma C
#4 0.4337835 2
test_pred <- predict(model, newdata= test.data)

confusionMatrix(table(test_pred, test.data$Species))

Confusion Matrix and Statistics


test_pred    setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         12          0         0
  versicolor      0         12         1
  virginica       0          0        11

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.9722          
                 95% CI : (0.8547, 0.9993)
    No Information Rate : 0.3333          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 4.864e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.9583          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
Sensitivity                 1.0000            1.0000           0.9167
Specificity                 1.0000            0.9583           1.0000
Pos Pred Value              1.0000            0.9231           1.0000
Neg Pred Value              1.0000            1.0000           0.9600
Prevalence                  0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
Detection Rate              0.3333            0.3333           0.3056
Detection Prevalence        0.3333            0.3611           0.3056
Balanced Accuracy           1.0000            0.9792           0.9583
```